# Get bash read command to understand spaces only

Tags: bash, variables, whitespace

I need to have the following work:

```
$ read -r -p 'input: ' foo
input: <space><space><space>
$ echo "text""$foo""more text"
text   more text
```

Where `<space><space><space>` is replaced with actual spaces.

However this is only possible if I set the variable manually:

```
$ foo='   '
$ echo "text""$foo""more text"
text   more text
```

I thought using `-r`, aka raw, would not mess with input like this. How can I perform such a task?

Using bash 3.2.57(1)-release under El Capitan, but am willing to install 3rd party tools if needed.

Comment: Though a good question, it is pretty much a duplicate of the linked one. Resetting the `IFS` should fix your problem. Do `IFS= read -r -p 'input: ' foo`

Comment: Additional info - http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#Trimming

Comment: Thanks @Inian, i admit was not easy to look since read is so common